# Multiple conditions in if statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-conditions

I am trying to cut down a list of gene names that I have been given. I'm trying to eliminate any repetitive names that may be present but I keep getting an error when running my code:

```
counter=0
i=0
j=0
geneNamesRevised=array(dim=length(geneNames))
for (i in 0:length(geneNamesRevised))
  geneNamesRevised[i]=""
geneNamesRevised
for (i in 1:length(geneNames))
  for (j in 1:length(geneNamesRevised))
    if (geneNames[i]==geneNamesRevised[j])
    {
      break
    }
    else if ((j==length(geneNamesRevised)-1) &&
             (geneNames[i]!=geneNamesRevised[j]))
    {
      geneNamesRevised[counter]=geneNames[i]
      counter++
    }
```

The error message is a repetitive string of :

the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedthe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be usedthe condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

and this error message is for the last "else if" statement that has the '&&'.

Thank you!

Comment: just try only one `&`. does it work?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just

```
geneNamesRevised <- unique( geneNames )
```

... which returns a shortened list. There is also a `duplicated` function that can be used to remove duplicates when negated.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems in your code.

1) The `else` is incorrectly specified - or not :)  thanks @Mohsen_Fatemi

2) & is usually what you need rather than &&

3) counter++ isn't R

Copy the code below and see if it runs

```
   for (i in 1:length(geneNames)){
     for (j in 1:length(geneNamesRevised)){
      if (geneNames[i]==geneNamesRevised[j])
      {
           break
      } else {

           if ((j==length(geneNamesRevised)-1) & (geneNames[i]!=geneNamesRevised[j]))
           {
                geneNamesRevised[counter]=geneNames[i]
                counter <- counter + 1
           }
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit**

4) also you were missing braces for your `for`s

Comment: you are wrong about `else if` , look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_if_else_statement.htm)

Answer (score 0):

use `&` instead of `&&` ,

```
else if ((j==length(geneNamesRevised)-1) & (geneNames[i]!=geneNamesRevised[j]))
```